# Reference variables in appsettings.json for NLog connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog, appsettings

I have this `appsettings.json` file in my project that looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=SQLSERVER;Database=MyDatabse;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "NLog": {
    "targets": {
      "database": {
        "type": "Database",
        "dbProvider": "System.Data.SqlClient",
        "connectionString": "Server=SQLSERVER;Database=MyDatabse;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do not want to write my connection string multiple places. Can I somehow reference the previous connection string?

I have already tried: `"connectionString": "${appsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.MyConnectionString}"`, which is not working.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Just *don't* use the same string in multiple places then. Modify your configuration objects so they don't have to load multiple strings. In this case though, you *shouldn't* try something like that at all. Logs don't have and possibly *shouldn't* be stored in an application's database for performance reasons at least

Comment: `appsettings.json` has no special meaning for .NET Core configuration anwyay - it's just another config source, the **same** as environment variables, databases, ini files etc. The default configuration would allow an environment variable or command-line argument to override the connection string as long as the proper name path is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NLog ConfigSetting Layout Renderer.

Just use this for your connection string in the NLog section:
`"connectionString": "${configsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.MyConnectionString}"`

Source:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 3):

**See @Jogge's answer to see how to reference connection string via NLog configuration.** My answer originally addressed the existence of such feature in default ASP.NET Core infrastructure and I didn't know NLog configuration offers such a feature.

### Old answer

Such a feature is not available in default ASP.NET application configuration via `appsettings.json`.

I definitely recommend not to store connection strings in your `appsettings.json` file anyway. Connection strings are sensitive data and should not be part of a file which is stored in plain text and potentially suspectible to attacks. In addition, `appsettings.json` is one of the checked-in files in Git, so the connection string would be visible in plain sight in git history. Instead, connection strings should be configured in the [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=windows) or via environment settings (for example Azure has a special UI for connection strings).

Comment: There are no secrets when Windows Authentication is used. Even with other authentication mechanisms there's no reason to store credentials in the connection string itself

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But this is not an answer. I already know the risks of having the connection string stored in the appsettings.

Comment: The answer is in the first sentence - I don't think there is any functionality for referencing other parts of the app settings file built in. The configuration system in ASP.NET Core aims for simplicity and such feature would be bound to cause significant complexity, especially because the config system is layered (so you can override values multiple times by different configuration sources)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24444529)

Comment: @Fareanor I am not sure why. I have provided the answer - it is not possible to do so in ASP.NET Core appsettings.json.

Comment: But I now see it is possible through NLog configuration, so I will remove my answer.

Comment: @MartinZikmund At time when I reviewed it, it was justified (You answered with an assumption based on what you think followed by a recommendation). But in-between, you have edited your answer, so my review became outdated and so, wrong :)

Comment: I haven't made it clear enough, as the answer was originally just a short part of the first sentence, sorry about that :-D .