# NLog on Blazor .NET 6: not logging on database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, blazor, blazor-server-side, nlog

I am trying to use NLog on a Blazor Server project, targeting .NET 6 , logging onto DB, but logs are not being written.
Can someone help me troubleshoot please?

I have this SQL Server table called `Logs`, which I assume NLog expects (correct me if I'm wrong).

[image]

Nuget packages:

[image]

This is my `nlog.config` from the root of the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog-AspNetCore.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- File Target for all log messages with basic details -->
    <!--
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    -->
    
    <!-- File Target for own log messages with extra web details using some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <!--
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}|${callsite}" />
    -->
    
    <!--Console Target for hosting lifetime messages to improve Docker / Visual Studio startup detection -->
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />
  
    <target name="database" type="Database">
 
        <dbprovider>mssql</dbprovider>

         <!-- database connection parameters -->
         <!-- alternatively you could provide a single 'connectionstring' parameter -->

        <connectionstring>DefaultConnection</connectionstring>

        <commandText>
            insert into Logs(createdon,level,logger,message) values(@time_stamp, @level, @logger, @message);
        </commandText>

        <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />

    </target>
  
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" appendTo="database" />

    <!--Output hosting lifetime messages to console target for faster startup detection -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" minlevel="Info" writeTo="lifetimeConsole" final="true" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs (BlackHole) -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

This is the relevant piece of my `appsettings.json`

```
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
```

This is my class in `Program.cs`

```
 public class Program
 {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromFile("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Trace("Program.Main: creating Host Builder");

            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection;
}
```

Even that `logger.Trace` call does not produce any log into the db.

Maybe my `Logs` table has either a wrong structure , or I need to explicitly indicate in the `nlog.config` which table and fields the logs are to be mapped to (but I guess the `<commandText>` tag should already do this).

Let me know - thanks

Comment: It is a good idea to enable the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and look for issues. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting (Ex. enable `throwConfigExceptions="true"`)

Comment: Are you using NLog through ILogger?

Comment: I think this could be helpful https://dev.to/mohammedahmed/store-log-messages-in-sql-server-for-your-aspnet-core-60-by-using-nlog-3dpb

Comment: @IvanMendoza I have upvoted you, nice alternative. Anyway the accepted solution (with my improvement in the comment) seemed quicker and effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your NLOG config you have:

```
<connectionstring>DefaultConnection</connectionstring>
```

NLog doesn't read your connection string from appsettings.json automatically, you need to provide it, for example:

```
<connectionstring>Data Source=your_server;Initial Catalog=your_database;User ID=your_username;Password=your_password;</connectionstring>
```

Alternative then you can use [${configsetting}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer) to perform lookup in appsettings.json:

```xml
<connectionstring>
${configsetting:ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}
</connectionstring>
```

Comment: According to the answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621956/reference-variables-in-appsettings-json-for-nlog-connection-string , would it work to use references like ${configsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection} ?
Because i don't like duplicating that constant in multiple places.

Comment: Answer to my last comment: yep it worked. Anyway i have accepted your answer even though it was not perfect :)
I suggest you to add this detail in your answer.